# AX form with WPF managedhost control can't be open a second time

Tags: c#, wpf, x++

I'm trying to create an AX form with a WPF managedhost control.

The form opens normally the first time, but if I close it and try to reopen it, nothing happens (no error message appears, it just do nothing)

Am I missing something ?

Here's my code :

AX :

```
public class FormRun extends ObjectRun
{
    SEP_Documentation.Customer  documentationControl;
    CustTable                   custTable;
}

public void init()
{    
    super();

    if (element.args().record())
    {
        custTable = element.args().record();
    }

    documentationControl = CustomerDocumentation.control();
    documentationControl.set_AXLanguage(new xInfo().language());
    documentationControl.set_User(curUserId());
    documentationControl.set_CustomerId(custTable.AccountNum);

    documentationControl.Init();
}
```

WPF :

```
public partial class Customer : UserControl
    {
        public string CustomerId { get; set; }
        public string User { get; set; }
        public string AXLanguage { get; set; }

        public Customer()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.CustomerDocuments.SelectionChanged += (obj, e) => Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Render, new Action(() => this.CustomerDocuments.UnselectAll()));
        }

        public void Init()
        {
            IEnumerable<APICustomerDocumentModel> documents = APIDocumentationRepository.GetCustomerDocuments(CustomerId, User, AXLanguage);

            this.CustomerDocuments.ItemsSource = documents;

            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo(AXLanguage);
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(AXLanguage);
            FrameworkElement.LanguageProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(FrameworkElement), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(XmlLanguage.GetLanguage(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.IetfLanguageTag)));
        }

        private void DocumentNameClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Hyperlink link = (Hyperlink)e.OriginalSource;
            Process.Start(link.NavigateUri.AbsoluteUri);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out the problem :

I add a try catch like this in my AX form :

```
try
{
    ...
}
catch (Exception::CLRError)
{
    ex = ClrInterop::getLastException();
    if (ex != null)
    {
        ex = ex.get_InnerException();
        if (ex != null)
        {
            error(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Then, I have been able to see where the problem was : the exception occured in this line in my WPF user control :

```
FrameworkElement.LanguageProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(FrameworkElement), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(XmlLanguage.GetLanguage(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.IetfLanguageTag)));
```

I guess user control are not fully closed when closing a form in AX, so a exception was thrown when the override metadata was already done.